# Where does the " " " " " " " " come from in DOM(no such thing in html)?

Tags: html, dom

You can locate the place by searching `test11" " " " " " " "` in the page,

but if you view the source code, you'll see the related html is like this:

```
test11<table style="display: table;" class="listview rowstyle-rowhighlight"" id="resourcegrid">
```

Where does the `" " " " " " " "` come from?

The problem can be seen [here](http://webmail.softgoo.com/demo.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code, it basically has the following structure:

```
<table>
   <tr> ... stuff ... </tr>
   "
   <tr> ... stuff ... </tr>
   "
   <tr> ... stuff ... </tr>
   etc
</table>
```

The browser does not know what to do with the quote characters between the `<tr>` (since it's not valid to have any content outside of the `<tr>`s) so it displays them before the table.

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS likely where the `content:` can put whatever content you want to put, also before and after, e.g.

```
cite:before { content: "\201C"; }
cite:after  { content: "\201D"; }
```

adds quoting before and after a cite tag

Comment: I don't find such css in the page,can you tell me which element has that css on?

Comment: see the class attribute? those space separated list must be defined somewhere; there's a long long list of css loaded in the html (the lines like `<style type="text/css" media="all">@import "/modules/book/book.css";</style>` you must search in those files too; you should check them all:D and try to understand how the "cascade" determine that behaviour. With luck, grep-ing into those files for "content:" could bring you swiftly to the point.

Answer (score 0):

For one, class="listview rowstyle-rohighlight"" has an extra ".

The <img> tags on Lines 369, 379, 389, 399, 409, 419, 429, 439 all have extra "s in their width and height attributes.

Lines 379, 389, 399, 409, 419, 429, 439 (Col 13 on all) have a rogue " after </tr>(")

Line 449, Col 13 has a rogue " between </tr>(")

So lines 379, 389, 399, 409, 419, 429, 439 and 449 are the 8 " that's appearing "test11"